# Removing data from service doesn't remove from component

Tags: angular

I have a service where I store some data used across my application, this is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService {
    public category: Array<any>;
    public client: Array<any>;

    public fetch(fetch: any): void {
        this.category = fetch.category;
        this.client = fetch.client;
    }

    public insert(array: string, object: any): void {
        return this[array].unshift(object);
    }

    public update(array: string, newObject: any): void {
        let object = this[array].find(obj => obj.id === newObject.id);

        if (object) {
            const index = this[array].indexOf(object);

            this[array][index] = { ...newObject };
            this[array] = [...this[array]];
        }
    }

    public remove(array: string, id: number): void {
        this[array] = this[array].filter(object => object.id !== id);
    }
}
```

And in my component I call these functions like this:

```
export class CategoryComponent {
    public category: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(
        private _store: StoreService,
    ) {
        this.category = this._store.category;
    }

    public insert() {
        // To simpify the code, let's assume the http request already happened
        // successfully and I received the response
        this._store.insert('category', response.object);
    }

    public update(category: any) {
        // To simpify the code, let's assume the http request already happened
        // successfully and I received the response
        this._store.update('category', response.object);
    }

    public remover(category: any) {
        // To simpify the code, let's assume the http request already happened
        // successfully and I received the response
        this._store.remove('category', category.id);
    }
}
```

When I add a new category item or update its value, the view updates the items automatically, I don't need to do anything else. However, when I want to remove an item from the category list, it doesn't remove the item from the HTML view.

If I use a `console.log` inside the remove function from the storeService I can see the object being removed properly from the array.

The only way I found to update the view is changing the component remove function to this:

```
public remove(category: any) {
    // To simpify the code, let's assume the http request already happened
    // successfully and I received the response
    this._store.remove('category', category.id);
    this.category = this._store.category;
}
```

If I do this the category item is removed from the HTML view. Why does it happen to remove one item but not when adding a new item or changing one value?

Comment: Why do you have this[array] = [...this[array]]; in the update?  Does adding that to the remove change anything?

Comment: you are probably loosing reference to the category here `this.category = this._store.category;` just make `this._store` public and ask it for category whenever needed

Comment: @Learning2Code No. Same thing happen. I still need to update this way `this.category = this._store.category;`

Answer (score 0):

In constructor you variable `this.category` becomes reference to `this._store.category`

When you call *remove()* new array returned from filter assign to `this._store.category` but at the same time `this.category` still references to old array

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is to return a new array from remove() and then use it like

```
this.category = this._store.remove('category', category.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you think about is correct. I suspect you have a problem with your data make sure that the `object` inserted with `insert(array: string, object: any)` has a unique Id

```
public remove(category: any) {

    this._store.remove('category', category.id);
    this.category = this._store.category;
}
```